# Are two finite-dimensional subspaces not disjoint iff the union of any of their bases is linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, notation, multisets

First I need to show the following Lemma:

**Lemma**
Let $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$ be finite-dimensional subspaces of $V$ with any bases $\mathcal{M}_{0}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{0}$. Then, $\mathcal{M}\cap\mathcal{N}\neq \{0\}$ if and only if $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ is linearly dependent.

**Proof.** Consider any bases $\mathcal{M}_{0},\mathcal{N}_{0}$ such that their union is linearly dependent. Then, $\sum\alpha_{i} m_{i} + \sum\beta_{i}n_{i}=0$ implies that, at least, $\alpha_{j},\beta_{i}\neq 0$ for some $i,j$. Thus, $\sum \alpha_{i} m_{i} = -\sum \beta_{i} n_{i} \neq 0$, which implies that a nonzero linear combination in $\mathcal{M}$ can be expressed as a linear combination in $\mathcal{N}$ and so $\mathcal{M}\cap\mathcal{N} \neq \{0\}$.

For the converse, assume that $\mathcal{M}\cap \mathcal{N}\neq \{0\}$. Hence, there is a nonzero vector $c\in \mathcal{M}\cap\mathcal{N}$ and so $c = \sum \alpha_{i}m_{i} = \sum\beta_{i}n_{i}$, where, at least, $\alpha_{i},\beta_{j} \neq 0$. Hence, $\sum\alpha_{i}m_{i} - \sum \beta_{i}n_{i} = 0$ and so $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup\mathcal{N}_{0} $ is linearly dependent.

**Q.E.D**

Now, consider two nontrivial subspaces $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ of $V$. In the case that $\mathcal{M}\cap \mathcal{N}\neq \{0\}$, there is a linearly independent set $C_{0}$ that spans $\mathcal{M}\cap\mathcal{N}$ and so one can extend it to bases $\mathcal{M}_{0}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{0}$. Hence, $M_{0}\cap\mathcal{N}_{0}=C_{0}$ and $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup\mathcal{N}_{0}$ is linearly dependent. However, I have seen in some proofs of the equality $\text{dim} \mathcal{M} + \text{dim} \mathcal{N} = \text{dim}(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{N}) + \text{dim}(\mathcal{M}\cap \mathcal{N})$ that $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{N}$, namely, $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ is linearly independent. There must be something wrong with my proof, hoever I'm pooped and need some help.
Thanks

Comment: $\mathcal M_0\cup \mathcal N_0$ cannot be a basis of $\mathcal M+\mathcal N$ as you started with a non-empty set $C_0$ which you then extended to both $\mathcal M_0$ and $\mathcal N_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yep, that's what I concluded. However, I have seen some proofs that use the fact that $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{N}$ to show that $\text{dim}\mathcal{M}+\text{dim}\mathcal{N}=\text{dim}(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{N})+\text{dim}(\mathcal{M∩N})$. That's why I am confused.

Comment: The definition of "linear dependence" only guarantees to you that at least *one* of the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ is nonzero; you need to do a bit of further argument to argue that in fact you must have at least one $\alpha_i$ nonzero, **and** one $\beta_j$ nonzero.  This is where you will use that each of $\mathcal{M}_0$ and $\mathcal{N}_0$ are bases, which is something you haven't used explicitly (though you used it implicitly when you aregued $\sum \alpha_im_i$ was nonzero).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, that's something I didn't state explicitly, but yeah, if only one of the scalars is nonzero, say $\alpha_{i}$, then $\sum \alpha m + \sum \beta n = \sum \alpha m + 0 = 0$, which implies that $\mathcal{M}_{0}$ is linearly dependent. The same argument can be used to state that at least one $\alpha$ and one $\beta$ must be nonzero (if only scalars of one type are nonzero, then one can conclude that the respective basis is linearly dependent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Lemma**
> Let $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$ be finite-dimensional subspaces of $V$ with any bases $\mathcal{M}_{0}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{0}$. Then, $\mathcal{M}\cap\mathcal{N}\neq \{0\}$ if and only if $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ is linearly dependent.

The lemma above is correct only if we interpret $\mathcal{M}_0\cup\mathcal N_0$ as the union of $\mathcal M_0$ and $\mathcal N_0$ as **multisets**, which is somewhat unconventional since "$\cup$" is used to denote the union of sets by default usually. For example, if $\mathcal{M}_{0}=\mathcal{N}_{0}=\{v\}$, then $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ means the multiset $[v,v]$, where $v$ is included two times.

Suppose we do interpret $\mathcal{M}_0\cup\mathcal N_0$ as the union of $\mathcal M_0$ and $\mathcal N_0$ as **multisets**. While your proof of the lemma cannot be marked as wrong, it lacks details as Arturo Magidin pointed out in [their comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4631186/are-two-finite-dimensional-subspaces-not-disjoint-iff-the-union-of-any-of-their/4631254#comment9770912_4631186).

---

On the other hand,  "in some proofs of the equality $\text{dim} \mathcal{M} + \text{dim} \mathcal{N} = \text{dim}(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{N}) + \text{dim}(\mathcal{M}\cap \mathcal{N})$", "$\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{N}$, namely, $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ is linearly independent." I would assume in those proofs, $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ is used to denote the union of $\mathcal{M}_{0}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{0}$ as **sets**. For example, if $\mathcal{M}_{0}=\mathcal{N}_{0}=\{v\}$, $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ will be the set $\{v\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, in the proofs of "$\text(dim)\mathcal{M}+\text{dim}\mathcal{N}=\text{dim}(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{N})+dim(\mathcal{M}∩\mathcal{N})$", $\mathcal{M}_{0}\cup \mathcal{N}_{0}$ denotes the union of sets. Regarding your comment about the proof, I see what happened. The argument follows because I consider, and repeat, all elements in the linear combinations $\sum \alpha_{i}m_{i} + \sum \beta_{i}n_{i}$, ignoring that the bases could share same elements? That's why I must assume that the bases $\mathcal{M}_{0},\mathcal{N}_{0}$ are multisets.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, which confirms the assumption I made in the last paragraph.